# Movie with a walled city, the walls pockmarked with holes breathing fire

Tags: story-identification

The movie was set in the 90s probably. It showed a group of people trying to infiltrate a city or a building which was surrounded by a huge wall. However, the walls were pockmarked with holes from which balls of fire shot out every few seconds/minutes, barely enough time to cross through. I remember that the protagonist successfully manages to infiltrate via them.

Comment: [Take a left, and then straight on through the chompers.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqRdT8m1Suo)

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. The answer is the same but there is no overlap of the questions. The linked question does not mention walls with holes shooting fire.

Comment: Don't think of a duplicate closure as a punishment. All it means is that you've both looking to identify the same property. Anyone who looks for this will find the answer over there.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sounds like this scene from Judge Dredd (1995).

Comment: That's a better clip than the one I could find!

Comment: @Michael Thank you, citizen.

Answer (score 9):

Judge Dredd, 1995?

Brief clip of him infiltrating the city via the vent, pursued by fire, around 1:12: